# too many fields in an android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have searched a lot for this but doesn't find anything helpful. My question is I have about 13 textviews with text fields as given below. I want them to be in one activity so the user can scroll down to fill all the fields. Help me how to handle this.

Name

Organization

Country

City

Contact#

Address

Zip

Amount

Duration

Card#

Currency

Expiry Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML layout you are looking for is the `<ScrollView>` although it can have one and only one child element. This means that you will wrap your `<Linear/RelativeLayout>` in the `<ScrollView>` so that your xml will resemble:

```
<ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout> <!-- or <RelativeLayout> -->
          <!-- all of your textviews and edit texts, etc. -->
     </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `scrollview` with the textviews in it so that the user can scroll down to see the rest of the information

Answer (score 0):

What about using `<ScrollView>`?

You just have to surround the part of your UI you want to be scrollable in the xml with a ScrollView element...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html